# I am having an issue with preg_split syntax

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am doing some tests moving from the function split to preg_split
in this line of code

```
list($tag) = preg_split('/[ >]/', substr($chunk, 2 - $open), 2);
```

What exactly do the `[]` do? Can they be omitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows any character in the set. That is the use of `[]` in RegEx (Regular Expressions).

Eg: `/[ABC]/` will match any capital letter of "A", "B" or "C".

Take a look at some information at http://www.regexr.com/. That should help a lot. It also allows you to see what will be picked up by testing your own search text with expressions.

Comment: `\s` is any whitespace character, not necessarily a space because newlines are included with that.

Comment: Edited, good catch. Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` chars define an char group. Any character in this group would be allowed.

So your code `/[ >]/` allow a space  or the `>` char. The `/` chars surround the regex expression.

=> Your regex split the input on every  or `>`